# How to Filter for multiple tags in LogCat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I'd like to filter my LogCat based on multiple TAG, How can I achieve this? Should I use Regex in order to filter by multiple TAG?

For example, I have this two lines of code which are used in my codes:

```
private static final String TAG1 = "My TAG 1";
private static final String TAG2 = "My TAG 2";
```

Can I filter out the LogCat to show both of them in the result?

Comment: Did you tried with "My TAG " keyword search

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this by enabling regex and entering:

```
(My TAG 1)|(My TAG 2)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work.  I tried
"Default" | "PK 1" 
and I don't get anything.  However entering in just
PK 1
does

Comment: The example matches the quotes as well from the question. I've improved the example the match only the tags.

Comment: multiple tags without any space work. i.e tag1|tag2

Comment: I use tags that include :  for project:class. It doesn't play well with tag:prj:class did not work. I needed to just write tag:class to get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

I have my LOGCAT filter setup like this:

```
package:mine (tag:MyTag1 | tag:MyTag2)
```

That way I can see messages from only `MyTag1` and `MyTag2` from my app.

Comment: You can add as many or (|) conditions as you like.

Comment: Using the equals didn't work for me, once I had removed both of them, this was what i needed. `package:mine (tag:MyTag1 | tag:MyTag2)`

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

```
package:mine (tag:TAG1 | tag:TAG2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
package:mine (tag:firstTag | secondTag)
```